# Want to get AVG for 2 columns but want to display results with an average Greater than 2

Tags: sql

Want to get AVG for 2 columns but want to only display results with an average Greater than 4. 
So far this is what I have

```
Select Category, 
(avg (Nomins) + avg (awards))/2 as "Avg Awards+Nomins" From DvdMovie 
Group By Category
Having (avg(Nomins) + avg(awards))/2 > 4
```

For some reason i'm not getting the right averages when I manually check it.

If this helps this is the question I'm trying to solve.

> Show for each movie category the average number of awards and nominations for movies in that category.
>    Only show categories where the average is 4 or more.

```
EDIT: Sample Data
1   Movie 1                         Action      70.00   2015    3   5
2   Movie 2                         Drama       65.00   2010    3   3
3   Movie 3                         Mystery     95.00   2016    5   6
4   Movie 4                         Horror      79.00   1975    3   4
5   Movie 5                         Sport       74.00   2005    2   2
6   Movie 6                         Comedy      81.00   2005    1   2
7   Movie 7                         Fantasy     19.00   2008    2   12
8   Movie 8                         Comedy      41.00   2004    4   9
9   Movie 9                         Horror      31.00   2009    1   1
10  Movie 10                        Fantasy     41.00   2009    0   2
11  Movie 11                        Horror      12.00   2009    1   2
```

Comment: i removed the extraneous database tags. please tag the one you are actually using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `having` clause from `Having (avg(Nomins) + avg(awards))/2 > 4` to `Having (avg(Nomins) + avg(awards))/2 >=4` and let us know.

EDIT:
In addition. there might be issues with truncation (due to integer division): I would suggest

```
SELECT 
    Category,  
    (AVG(CONVERT(float, nomins + awards)) ) / 2.0 
    as "Avg Awards+Nomins"
FROM dvdmovie
GROUP BY Category
HAVING (AVG(CONVERT(float, nomins + awards)) ) >= 8
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that and i'm still not getting the right answer. I think there's a problem with how I wrote the avg clause because when I'm manually calculating the avg on a calculator I'm getting an answer of 8 but when I'm running the script I'm getting 3.

Comment: I updated my answer, if the problem persists please post some sample data.

Comment: I added the data that i'm using. The average for fantasy movies should be 8 but when I run it I'm getting 4 for fantasy movies. I tried what you suggested and still not getting the right answer.

Comment: I don't get it 100%. What is the expected average for Action?

Comment: The expected average is 4 for action and I'm getting that correct when I run it. But I'm just wondering how come fantasy is coming up as 4 shouldn't the expected average for it be 16?

Comment: If avg(action) = 4, this means that if you had two identical rows for action the average would still be 4. These two rows would have sum(nomins) + sum(awards) = 2*(3 + 5) = 16, so two rows with total sum = 16 yield average 4. This is exactly what you have for Fantasy (two rows with total sum = 16).

Comment: No problem! Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer has solved your problem perhaps you would consider accepting it!